# Google Chrome Extension: How to open a new tab in a discarded/hibernating state?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a Google Chrome Extension that involves creating new tabs. I want to be able to create lots of tabs at once, but I don't want them all to load at the same time. I just want to add the tab to the window and have it reload when it becomes active. Is this something that the Google Chrome Extension API supports? Or is this something I will need to build myself (use a placeholder page that loads the correct URL when active)?

Comment: Not implemented, see https://crbug.com/879838. Meanwhile you can create tabs with a URL like `'data:text/html,<title>foo'`, then use onActivated listener to update the tab to its real URL (which you can store in the background script or storage or even include in the data URL as a dummy tag). Some tab managers open an html page from the extension.

Comment: @wOxxOm good advice. You should post that as an answer!

Comment: I thought it might be better if you post an answer yourself with bits of real code...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question as you, and thanks to @wOxxOm comment I was able to answer it.

Here is my implementation, as it might help someone.

**manifest.json**

```json
{
    ...
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
    ...
}
```

It's important to handle 'onActivated' event in a background script, otherwise it will only work while the extension panel is open.

**index.js**

```js
const link = 'https://stackoverflow.com/';

// Create new tab with our link as title
chrome.tabs.create({
    url:  'data:text/html,<title>' + link,
    active: false
});
```

**background.js**

```js
// When the new tab is selected, get the link in the title and load the page
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(({tabId, windowId}) => {
    const splitText = 'data:text/html,<title>';
    
    chrome.tabs.get(tabId, tab => {
        if (tab.url.startsWith(splitText)) {
            const realTabUrl = tab.url.replace(splitText, '')

            chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {
                url: realTabUrl, 
            });
        }
    });
})
```